# Prove $H < N$ if $N\triangleleft G$, $[G : N]$ finite, $H < G$, $|H|$ finite, and $[G : N]$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $N\triangleleft  G$, $[G : N]$ finite, $H < G$, $|H|$ finite, and $[G : N]$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime, then $H < N$.

Since $N \triangleleft G$, $HN/N \cong H/(H∩N)$, and $HN < G$. By $[G : N] < ∞$ and $|H ∩N| ≤ |H| < ∞$,

$[G : N] = [G : HN][HN : N] = [G : HN] (|HN|/|N|) = [G : HN] (|H|/|H ∩ N|)$,

and so $[G : N]|[G : HN]|H|$. As $[G : N]$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime, $[G : N]|[G : HN]$. It follows that $[G : N] = [G : HN]$, and so $[H : H ∩ N] = [HN : N] = 1$, which implies $H < N$.

I have some questions about this exercise:

Is $NH$ normal in $G$ and why?

why $[G:N]|[G:HN]$ implies that they are equal? and why implies that $H < N$?

Thanks for your comments I want to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, $\;HN\;$ not necessarily normal in $\;G\;$ . Why do you think it is?

2) By the assumption: $\;[G:N]\,\mid\,[G:HN]\;$ , we get $\;[G:HN]=k\cdot[G:N]. \;$ But $\;N\le HN\;$ , so

$$[G:N]=[G:HN]\cdot [HN:N]=k\cdot[G:N][HN:N]\implies k[HN:N]=1\implies$$

$$N=HN\implies H\le N$$

Comment: My teacher told me that $HN$ is normal in $G$, and I dont know why

Comment: @Salvattore Either he got confused or else it is given also $\;H\;$ is normal...or he just doesn't know.

Answer (score 1):

You know always that $[G:N]\geq [G:NH]$ since $N\leq NH$. If $[G:N]|[G:NH]$, then in particular $[G:N]\leq [G:NH]$ and they are equal.
$HN$ does'nt have to be normalm, but the index is defined for all sungroups - it is the number of cosets